# Facing issues while testing connectivity from docker container to validator. curl http://rest-api:8008/blocks

Tags: docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

Background: setting up the environment for Hyperledger- Sawtooth.

Running command curl http://rest-api:8008/blocks  to test the connectivity of Validator from Client Container.
getting error:
could not resolve host rest-api

Comment: Is `rest-api` the name of your service or container? Are the two containers on the same user defined network? Please include all the steps that can be used to reproduce your issue. [mcve]

Comment: here rest-api is a service. 
First I ran 
$ docker-compose -f sawtooth-default.yaml up

Comment: here rest-api is a service. 
First I ran below command to download the docker images
$ docker-compose -f sawtooth-default.yaml up
The logged into the container using below command
$ docker exec -it sawtooth-shell-default bash
then inside the 
root@75b380886502:/# 
I am running 
$ curl http://rest-api:8080/blocks
to confirm that our validator is up and running, and reachable from the client container.

Comment: If we try to run that command, it would say sawtooth-default.yaml is not found. Since we are not in your machine, you'll need to provide all the details to replicate your problem on another machine. [mcve] (note the "complete" part of that guide)

Comment: Thanks BMitch, I think complete replication will be time taking for you as this process involves installing docker and other things, I am getting this error on last stage of installing the sawtooth hyperledger where we are checking if Validator is up and running fine.

Comment: Can you post the `rest` portion of the yaml as well as what you see when you do `docker ps -a`

Comment: Thanks Frank, You open my mind, I just checked the yaml file and saw that rest-api is bind to 8008 port and not to 8080 which i was using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [sawtooth-local-installed.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-core/blob/master/docker/compose/sawtooth-local-installed.yaml) from the Sawtooth master branch, then the REST API service is exposed on port 8008 on the `rest-api` container, and also forwarded to port 8008 on the host:

```
rest-api:
  image: sawtooth-rest-api:latest
  container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-default
  expose:
    - 8008
  ports:
    - "8008:8008"
  depends_on:
    - validator
  entrypoint: sawtooth-rest-api --connect tcp://validator:4004 --bind rest-api:8008
```

The service should therefore be accessible from another Docker container as http://rest-api:8008/blocks or from the host as http://127.0.0.1:8008/blocks via a web browser or curl. If you are still having problems, try changing the `entrypoint` command to use `--bind 0.0.0.0:8008` as the last argument.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out, have checked the yaml file and it was 8008.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this command, it will work

```
 curl http://rest-api-0:8008/blocks
```

this is because the `rest-api-0` is mentioned in the docker file.