# Hyperledger sawtooth installation problems (with docker). No connectivity between client container and REST api

Tags: docker, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to setup a sawtooth node for testing with docker in ubuntu like in the tutorial:

https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/1.2/app_developers_guide/installing_sawtooth.html

After downloading the Docker images for the Sawtooth environment I check that the containers are up with `docker ps`:
[running containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn9Uh.png)

and then I connect to the client and run:

```
curl http://rest-api:8008/blocks
```

to confirm that the REST-API and validator are reachable by the client but the command returns nothing so we have a connectivity issue.

On the other hand, connectivity from the host machine seems to be working. I have seen that most people encountered this issue instead of mine.

This is the part of the configuration file sawtooth-default.yaml consering the rest-api container.

```
rest-api:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-default
    ports:
      - "8008:8008"
    depends_on:
      - validator
    entrypoint: sawtooth-rest-api -C tcp://validator:4004 --bind rest-api:8008
```

I have tried the solutions proposed here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568174/facing-issues-while-testing-connectivity-from-docker-container-to-validator-cur](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
but to no use.

Since I also use docker for the first time, I have a feeling I messed up sth during during docker installation.

Does anyone know what might be the source of the problem?
Thank you

Comment: You might have to create a network between two containers… your validator image and another image that you are using..Not sure about sawtooth.. check docker networking concepts it might help you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected, the source of the problem was some mistake I did during the installation of docker.

More specificaly, I configured docker to use a proxy server even thought I am not behind one so communication between containers was hindered. Once I fixed this, the client could communicate properly with the validator.